# computer connected to internet by wifi but printing delayed

Tags: printing

I'm an amateur.
Computer connected to internet by wifi but printing on network printer is delayed by more than ten minutes. Using 20.04. In the interim sits in queue.  The active interface mtu (wlp1s0) was 1500; changed to 1492.  Still a delay of about 15 minutes (unchanged).

Comment: See the print queues with `lpstat -t`, check the CUPS logs with `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups`. Check your WiFi MTU with `ip list`. It should be `1492`, not `1500`.

Comment: Printer make and model?

Comment: printer is hp LaserJet P1600dn.  Now figuring out how to give longer answers to answers.

Comment: mtu is 1500. what do i do about it.